# Is there a jQuery selector function that can reference relative elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here are some examples, which I would expect to work with `$`:

```
$(':target', element); // Should return element
$(':parent', element); // Should return parent of element
$(':parent textarea', element); // Should return textareas within parent of element
```

The reason I don't want to use the `parent` method is because the selector will be dynamic, and I don't want to have to parse it.

**Edit**:

Here's a concrete example.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span data-hide=":parent span:eq(1)">Span 1</span>
    <span>Span 2</span>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('[data-hide]').on('click', function()
{
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-hide');
    $(selector, $(this)).hide();
});
```

If the 2nd parameter of `$` (called `context`) and `:parent` pseudo selector worked the way I expected, clicking "Span 1" would hide "Span 2".

But it doesn't. So how can I write this function so that any reasonable absolute or relative selector can be used?

Comment: no... there are no selectors called `:parent` or `:target`... why do you want it

Comment: It sounds like you should review the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: What you want from `$(':target', element)` is essentially the same as `$(this)` from within a bound event callback.

Comment: @Arun P Johny: Actually, there are, they just don't do what is being asked.

Comment: @BoltClock yes that was what I meant

Comment: Can you elaborate on your last statement? The `.parent()` method operates on a jQuery element set (which I'm assuming is what `element` represents in your code), independently of the selector that was used to match those elements. It shouldn't matter whether the selector was hardcoded, generated, or even obtained from the user.

Comment: Oh I get it now. You're talking about the first parameter, not the one in `element`.

Comment: Just came across your question (a year late) and happen to have come up with a solution for the same problem. Better late then never I say :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement (basically search up then down the DOM using a single string selector), and after digging into how selectors work I found this was not possible with normal selectors as the evaluation of the selector elements is *right-to-left*, whereas you need *left-to-right* to make your suggestion work. I was able to make a custom selector that could have a `:this` reference, which can let you do similar searches including `:has(:this)`. I have repeated my answer here from [Is it possible to create custom jQuery selectors that navigate ancestors? e.g. a :closest or :parents selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721390/is-it-possible-to-create-custom-jquery-selectors-that-navigate-ancestors-e-g-a/25733588#25733588)

Based on numerous comments, and one detailed explanation on why *this is impossible*, it occurred to me that the aim I wanted could be met with a `$(document).find()`, but with some concept of *targeted elements*. That is, some way to target the original query elements, within the selector.

To that end I came up with the following, a `:this` selector, which works like this (no pun intended):

```
// Find all labels under .level3 classes that have the .starthere class beneath them
$('.starthere').findThis('.level3:has(:this) .label')
```

**This allows us to now, effectively, search up the DOM then down into adjacent branches in a single selector string!** i.e. it does the same job this does (but in a single selector):

```
$('.starthere').parents('.level3').find('.label')
```

### Steps:

1 - Add a new `jQuery.findThis` method

2 - If the selector has `:this`, substitute an id search and search from `document` instead

3 - If the selector does not contain a `:this` process normally using the original `find`

4 - Test with selector like `$('.target').find('.ancestor:has(:this) .label')` to select a label within the ancestor(s) of the targetted element(s)

This is the revised version, based on comments, that does not replace the existing find and uses a generated unique id.

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/z3vwk1ko/36/

```
// Add findThis method to jQuery (with a custom :this check)
jQuery.fn.findThis = function (selector) {
    // If we have a :this selector
    if (selector.indexOf(':this') > 0) {
        var ret = $();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            var el = this[i];
            var id = el.id;
            // If not id already, put in a temp (unique) id
            el.id = 'id'+ new Date().getTime();
            var selector2 = selector.replace(':this', '#' + el.id);
            ret = ret.add(jQuery(selector2, document));
            // restore any original id
            el.id = id;
        }
        ret.selector = selector;
        return ret;
    }
    // do a normal find instead
    return this.find(selector);
}

// Test case
$(function () {
    $('.starthere').findThis('.level3:has(:this) .label').css({
        color: 'red'
    });
});
```

**Known issues:**

- This leaves a blank `id` attribute on targetted elements that did not have an `id` attribute to begin with (this causes no problem, but is not as neat as I would like)
- Because of the way it has to search from document, it can only emulate `parents()` and not `closest()`, but I have a feeling I can use a similar approach and add a `:closest()` pseudo selector to this code.

*This was based on 6 hours slaving over jQuery/Sizzle source code, so be gentle*. Always happy to hear of ways to improve this replacement `find` as I am new to the internals of jQuery :)

**You can then solve your original problem with something like this:**

```
<div>
    <span data-hide="div:has(:this) span:eq(1)">Span 1</span>
    <span>Span 2</span>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('[data-hide]').on('click', function()
{
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-hide');
    $(this).findThis(selector).hide();
});
```