# jQuery closest (inside and outside DOM tree )

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given an element and **any** selector, I need to find the closest element which matches it, not matter if it's inside the element or outside of it.

Currently jQuery doesn't provide such traversing functionality, but there is a need. Here is the scenario:

A list of many items where the `<button>` element reside inside `<a>`

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>
      <button>click me</button>
      <img src="..." />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <button>click me</button>
      <img src="..." />
    </a>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Or the `<button>` element might reside outside of the `<a>` element

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="..." />
    </a>
    <button>click me</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="..." />
    </a>
    <button>click me</button>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

The very very basic code would look like this:

```
$('a').closest1('button'); // where `closest1` is a new custom function
// or
$('a').select('> button') // where `select` can parse any selector relative to the object, so it would also know this:
$('a').select('~ button') // where the button is a sibling to the element
```

the known element is `<a>` and anything else can change. I want to locate the nearest `<button>` element for a given `<a>` element, no matter if that button is inside or outside of `<a>`'s DOM tree.

It would be very logical that native jQuery function "[closest](http://jqapi.com/#p=closest)" would do as the name suggests and find the closest, but it only searches upwards as you all know. (it should have been named differently IMO).

---

Does anyone know any custom traversing function which does the above? 
Thanks. (i'm asking you people because someone must have written this for sure but I was unlucky to find a lead on the internet)

Comment: None of the built-in selectors allow searching up *and* down the tree. I did create a custom `findThis` extension that allows you to do things like `$elementClicked.('li:has(this) button') ` which would allow you to do something similar. Is that of interest to you?

Comment: yes i know jquery has nothing built-in, this is why i'm asking of course. does your function has the ability to work like the demo pseudo code i've envisioned this to work like? thanks

Comment: This _feels_ like an XY problem... you'd have to potentially search the entire DOM?

Comment: Yes, I think it will handle you test cases. Give me a minute to create a JSfiddle to demo it.

Comment: You didn't specify the restriction on how far at most the searched element (button) must be located from the anchor element (a)

Comment: I think you're looking at this problem as if the DOM is a flat list. Because it's a tree, that relationship has meaning. Finding the *closest* in your terms seems like the structure is wrong, rather than something which needs solved.

Comment: @JamesThorpe - many selectors has the potential of search much of a DOM (mostly not all of it, but a big part). I would say, the selector would have to part the selection string and internally use the right jquery selector for the job.

Comment: Okay. Working solution added that works for both cases.

Comment: @RGraham - i'm not looking at this wrong at all. I am looking to parsing something which I we can call "mega selector", and internally that selector would be parsed and the right jquery selector would be utilized to find what the user was after, like the code I envisioned in my question.

Comment: @RGraham: I hit a similar problem months ago, where in my case I needed single selectors to provide an up-down search capability. The `findThis` extension below allows that. Taken from my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721390/is-it-possible-to-create-custom-jquery-selectors-that-navigate-ancestors-e-g-a/25733588#25733588

Comment: It's usually a fairly defined subset though, whereas this would need to scan through every sibling, child, parent (and the children and parents of those) etc etc to check if it had one "closer" than one it's already found.  It's also not like it's just keeping track of the found elements, it's also then having to determine which one is "closest".

Comment: I fully understand the required solution. I just don't understand what problem it solves. I can't understand why an element, in a potentially completely unrelated part of the DOM tree, would be semantically linked to the original element without some sort of identifying attributes.

Comment: @RGraham - fine question. I have built an image gallery, which is a quite complex one (https://github.com/yairEO/photobox) and a use has opened an issue where he wants to enlarge an image not by clicking on the links themselves which is the default behavior, but by placing a button somewhere in the DOM, for each image item, and that element will trigger the enlargement of an image. now, that button could be anywhere..but each `<a>` element will have a button, hence, my question was born

Comment: What if it's something like `<ul><li><a><img></a></li><li><a><img></a></li></ul><button><button>` - the first button is "closest" to _both_ `a` elements?

Comment: `data-` attributes, linking the elements, would be a more practical solution if your DOM has no structure at all. Otherwise you might as well code up a custom search.

Comment: @JamesThorpe - well, for this use case the DOM cannot look like that, and nobody would use this custom traversing for such a DOM, since it is not meant for that. it is only meant for cases as I have described above. Like any other selector in jQuery, it would have it's own scenario of uses.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - yes i am talking about custom search here. I want to make this transparent and handle it internally rather than asking people who use my code to change their existing DOM to add `data` attributes.

Comment: ok - so is it limited to just your two examples then (ish - will the button always be inside the `li` say?).  If so, just find the closest li, then the button within it?  `$(this).closest('li').find('button')`? (assuming you can't use attributes to semantically link them, which seems like the appropriate solution here)

Comment: @James Thorpe: Funny enough that is exactly what `findThis` emulates below, but in a single selector (which I presumed, *apparently incorrectly*, was the overall aim).

Comment: @JamesThorpe - I wouldn't count on that. every list item could have a button somewhere in it, but I can't know where, relative to the `<a>` element. only the HTML implementer would know that, so he/she could  also provide my plugin with some form of a selector which would say where there button is relative to the link. like `+ + button` would be go up two levels and search from there, or maybe  `~ button` would be a sibling to the link. therefor i could not use the `find` method internally if it's a sibling

Comment: @vsync I think either you need to use attributes to link them, or expose an API point to allow your consumers to specify either a selector or a callback function that given an element, returns the button since they'll know how to get from one to the other.

Comment: I think I will go with asking the user to just point to some parent which he would know all buttons would exist inside it. something like `li` because the user knows that would be a repeating pattern, every link and button will be inside an `li` element, so then i could just internally do `$('a').closest([user selector]).find('button')`. it's not what I wanted but it would work.

Comment: Added a second (really simple) answer based on my suggested alternative. Hope that matches you needs better :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - solved this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29823718/104380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [DEMO PAGE](http://jsbin.com/rasere/5/edit) / [GIST](https://gist.github.com/yairEO/c5f85be5bf7f583f3d5eaf3dce1a5287)

I have solved working by logic, so I would first look inside the elements, then their siblings, and last, if there are still unfound items, I would do a recursive search on the parents.

### JS CODE:

```
jQuery.fn.findClosest = function (selector) {
    // If we have a :this selector
    var output = $(), 
        down = this.find(selector),
        siblings,
        recSearch,
        foundCount = 0;

    if(down.length) {
        output = output.add(down);
        foundCount += down.length;
    }

    // if all elements were found, return at this point
    if( foundCount == this.length )
      return output;

    siblings = this.siblings(selector);

    if( siblings.length) {
        output = output.add(siblings);
        foundCount += siblings.length;
    }
    
    // this is the expensive search path if there are still unfound elements

    if(foundCount < this.length){
        recSearch = rec(this.parent().parent());
        if( recSearch )
            output = output.add(recSearch);
        
    }

    function rec(elm){
        var result = elm.find(selector);
        if( result.length )
          return result;
        else
          rec(elm.parent());
    }

    return output;
};

// Test case

var buttons = $('a').findClosest('button');

console.log(buttons);

buttons.click(function(){
  this.style.outline = "1px solid red";
})
```

Comment: This still needs an improvement, but that I feel this is the right way to go

Comment: Best remove my comments too. Makes your code confusing. Note: A sibling check is redundant if you are travelling up the ancestors anyway. I think that was covered in comments. As this is in response to a click, speed is not an issue at all. My short/simple answer does the same thing in one line so not sure why you bothered with this much code. Your call. :)

Comment: I tried your code in a JSFiddle and could not get it to work as-is: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/vsgj2Ldf/ Can you modify that JSFiddle? Once working we can try some JSPerf tests to see if the code was worth the effort :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - checking

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - it doesn't work because you need to set the code execution on the left side to "onDomReady" or "onLoad" since if it's in the `head` it wouldn't find any `<a>` elements. Why would you prefer jsfiddle over jsBin may I ask?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another attempt using the idea I mentioned in comment:

```
$(this).parents(':has(button):first').find('button').css({
        "border": '3px solid red'
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/z3vwk1ko/40/

It basically looks for the first ancestor that contains both the elements (clicked and target), then finds the target.

### Performance:

With regard to speed, this is used at human interaction speeds, i.e. a few times per second *maximum*, so being a "slow selector" is irrelevant if it solves the problem, in a reasonably obvious way, with minimal code. You would have to click 100s of times per second to notice any different compared to a *fast* selector :)

Comment: I think this is pretty close - so long as the buttons live somewhere relatively near each image.  Certainly solves the examples given

Comment: that is a pretty slow selector :)

Comment: @vsync: What on Earth were you expecting, speed-wise, from your requirements? My other answer is quite efficient, but requires a starting point (some common ancestor element). At least you now have two choices more than you had before :)

Comment: please see my answer and tell me your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

None of the built-in selectors allow searching up *and* down the tree. I did create a custom `findThis` extension that allows you to do things like `$elementClicked.('li:has(this) button')` which would allow you to do something similar.

```
// Add findThis method to jQuery (with a custom :this check)
jQuery.fn.findThis = function (selector) {
    // If we have a :this selector
    if (selector.indexOf(':this') > 0) {
        var ret = $();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            var el = this[i];
            var id = el.id;
            // If not id already, put in a temp (unique) id
            el.id = 'id' + new Date().getTime();
            var selector2 = selector.replace(':this', '#' + el.id);
            ret = ret.add(jQuery(selector2, document));
            // restore any original id
            el.id = id;
        }
        ret.selector = selector;
        return ret;
    }
    // do a normal find instead
    return this.find(selector);
}

// Test case
$(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        $(this).findThis('li:has(:this) button').css({
            "border": '3px solid red'
        });
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/z3vwk1ko/38/

note: Click the images/links to test.

Comment: i don't want to involve the `li` in the selector, but it automatically relative to the element (<a> in this case). decoupling markup from selectors as much as possible

Comment: @vsync. There has to be some for of limiting, or you will have to trawl all parents until you get a match, but who is to say a single match is enough. You are likely to have some form of container in your code, it can be broad, but otherwise you are basically searching all `parents` in turn until you `find` a single match. That is relative slow.

Comment: that is how `closest` work already. all I want it to do is to expand it's functionality, so it would first look inside, and if the element wasn't found, then look up the DOM. is all. I assume here that the inside DOM is not big, and would be "cheaper" to search in first and only if not found, traverse up. would you agree?

Comment: Not possible with a single jQuery Sizzle selector, as it works right to left and will not allow upward referencing. I know as I spent a lot of time inside the Sizzle source code trying to  solve this problem, before coming up with the above answer. You would need to replace Sizzle.

Comment: It's not just down and up the dom though.  You need to search down, then up, then across at every level on the way up, and down within each of those etc etc.

Comment: @James Thorpe: `down` from ancestors is enough to find a common parent (across not needed). Worst case you hit `body` for every search (then he is in trouble) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie that's true.  You'd still need to count each of the levels passed through to find the "closest" one though.

Comment: @James Thorpe: Nah, Just sequentially check down from each parent as you move upwards through ancestors. Stop on first match. Horribly slow, but I think this is all beside this point. Totally unstructured content is not a good idea for efficiency :)

Comment: mind you that inside the `<li>` could be a much more complex DOM than what I've written, so just going to the parent of the element and searching from there wouldn't be suffice.

Comment: @vsync: Who said anything about parent? I literally mean `parents()` (all the ancestors).

Comment: yeah well basically I could ask the user to provide a starting reference point of where to start the search for that element. that would be an ugly solution to the problem. the real problem here is lack of technological means to just search anything relative to something, no matter inside or outside.

Comment: Anyway, I have written a new search function and published it as an answer so check it out, tell me any thoughts you might have ans thanks for taking the time to participate in this discussion which sadly got downvoted

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I wanted to do the same for a completely DOM-based text editor, and needed to find the previous (<kbd>ARR LEFT</kbd>) and next (<kbd>ARR RIGHT</kbd>) text nodes, both *up and down the tree*. Based on this code I have made an adaptation suiting this question. Be warned, it's quite performance-heavy, but it is adapted to any scenario. There are two functions `findPrevElementNode` and `findNextElementNode` which both return an object with properties:

- match - returns the closest matching node for the search or `FALSE` if none is found
- iterations - returns the number of iterations done to find the node. This allows you to check whether the previous node is closer than the next or vice-versa.

The parameters are as follows:

```
 //@param {HTMLElement} referenceNode - The node from which to start the search
 //@param {function} truthTest - A function that returns true for the given element
 //@param {HTMLElement} [limitNode=document.body] - The limit up to which to search to
```

```
var domUtils = {
    findPrevElementNode: function(referenceNode, truthTest, limitNode) {
        var element = 1, 
            iterations = 0,
            limit = limitNode || document.body,
            node = referenceNode;
        while (!truthTest(node) && node !== limit) {
            if (node.previousSibling) {
                node = node.previousSibling;
                iterations++;
                if (node.lastChild) {
                    while (node.lastChild) {
                        node = node.lastChild;
                        iterations++;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (node.parentNode) {
                    node = node.parentNode;
                    iterations++;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return {match: node === limit ? false : node, iterations: iterations};
    },
    findNextElementNode: function(referenceNode, truthTest, limitNode) {
        var element = 1, 
            iterations = 0,
            limit = limitNode || document.body,
            node = referenceNode;
        while (!truthTest(node) && node !== limit) {
            if (node.nextSibling) {
                node = node.nextSibling;
                iterations++;
                if (node.firstChild) {
                    while (node.firstChild) {
                        node = node.firstChild;
                        iterations++;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (node.parentNode) {
                    node = node.parentNode;
                    iterations++;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return {match: node === limit ? false : node, iterations: iterations};
    }
};
```

In your case, you could do:

```
var a = domUtils.findNextElementNode(
    document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0], // known element
     function(node) { return (node.nodeName === 'BUTTON'); }
);
var b = domUtils.findPrevElementNode(
    document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0], // known element
     function(node) { return (node.nodeName === 'BUTTON'); }
);

var result = a.match ? (b.match ? (a.iterations < b.iterations ? a.match : 
  (a.iterations === b.iterations ? fnToHandleEqualDistance() : b.match)) : a.match) : 
  (b.match ? b.match : false);
```

See it [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/p5z4c346/2/).

Comment: please see my answer, which is much more simple

Comment: @vsync Yours is indeed much simpler, but it also 1) requires jQuery,  and 2) only has 1 parameter (which is totally good, because it could be enough). Btw remember mine is based on *a piece of code I wrote before for finding the **next** and **previous** elements*. So thanks, I just saw there's one case where my code falls short: when the element is inside the `referenceNode` and has siblings, this will fail.

Comment: This question is about jQuery selectors after all, so I have no problem with the first argument :)

Comment: This would be more impressive if I could verify it worked with the previous sample HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/z3hdzp9b/ Can you correct this JSFiddle? Your own JSFiddle does not seem to work either.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie How do you mean it does not work? Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/z3hdzp9b/1/, the button will be colored with red borders & the amount of iterations next to it. As I mentioned in my comment above, there's one flaw in this code (because it was originally designed to find next/ prev), might refactor it if i find some time. vsync yeah np, I'm just always curious about how to do it in plain JS

Comment: "Does not work": as in click the first image and first button should be selected. Click the second image and the second button should be selected :) Try one of the other answers' JSFiddles to see the expected behavior (i.e. just target the "nearest" required element).

Comment: Like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/z3hdzp9b/2/ (it's on third image), you can change it by setting the `link` var.

Comment: Yes, all 4 should work like that third one. Does that mean your answer is hard-wired to one specific result? Given a choice between all that raw JS and simply `$(this).parents(':has(button):first').find('button')`, which do you think users will understand/maintain easier? Is RAW JS really the way to go?  (well done on attempting it though) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I'm not saying raw JS is the way to go, this function is just a refactoring of previous ones for another purpose. As such it is not polished and might fail on occasions (for example check: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/z3hdzp9b/3/, bound to all images, but first one fails because it is inside the same parent). If I get around to refactoring it to this specific purpose I'll post an @ comment =), but still jQuery might outperform this (jsPerf's needed)... so by all means if the jQuery function works, go for that.

Comment: As this is at "click speed" only, I am more concerned with maintenance/readability than raw speed. Performance should not be a factor here  :)

Answer (score -1):

I think using sibling selector (~)  or child selector (>) will solve your purpose(What ever your case is!!).

Comment: me? this is a serious question. this is not a joke you can just simply downvote as non-constructive. I never asked **anyone** to upvote anything, ever in my life. I find your comment a bit offensive

Comment: @vsync: what are you talking about? I simple meant a friend (of his) must have uprooted it as it is not even relevant. *sigh*. Some day it does not pay to get out of bed . :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - ho, my bad sorry I mistaken the comment meaning for something else. Anyway, nowadays you can do internet from bed so you could say it does not pay to open your eyes at all in the morning :)